# Grabbing CSV over cURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl, csv, fopen

Unfortunately, I cannot use either fopen or file_get_contents, so my working script has become a broken one using cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$tmp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header(Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$start.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
echo $tmp;
```

URL going in is a CSV file - and the fopen version of this worked before. All I get is an empty CSV file returned to the browser.

Thanks.

Comment: try first to see if you get any output before you send ``csv`` headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok there could be a couple of places which went wrong, most likely the $tmp variable will be your key.

I am assuming the $url and $start variables have been declared correctly

First thing I would suggest is to do something along the lines of:

```
    if( ! $tmp = curl_exec($ch))
        {
           echo curl_error($ch);
        } 

    else
    {

        header("Content-type: application/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$start.csv");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");
        echo $tmp;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```

Might give you an idea about what is going wrong

Comment: Does the above code fetch the CSV or simply show more information for the curl request?

Answer (score 4):

By default `curl_exec` returns a boolean. You need to set the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option to `1` or `true` to get the transfer payload returned.

Comment: This option is probably the cause

Answer (score 1):

Set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to 1 so you get something into $tmp, otherwise curl_exec outputs the csv directly (and before you send the headers). See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `curl_exec($ch)` will not return a string unless you use `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true)` first.