# I can't download a csv file with curl in a php script

Tags: php, csv, curl, download, libcurl

I've got a problem when I try to download a file from a remote third party server using curl in my php script.

The file is a csv, and I think it is created by a script that read data from a database. Infact to obtain that file you have to fill an HTML form with some parameters (like month and year). I use curl to log into the server and send the values that populate the form but when I try to save the response to a local file i get html code of the download page instead of the csv file.

Here's my code:

```
    $fp = fopen(getcwd()."\patti.csv", "w+");

    $ch = curl_init($urlPatti);//the url of the download page
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postfields);//parameters to send
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
    $errorMsg=curl_error($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    fclose($fp);
```

this is the header that i receive from the page:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 22 Aug 2013 08:59:39 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Last-Modified: Thu, 22 Aug 2013 08:59:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Via: 1.1 ido.venetolavoro.it
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Comment: Maybe you missed a parameter?

Comment: Can you use wget or the curl command line tool to retrieve the file?

Comment: @frits van campen: What parameter? Can you tell me?

Comment: @Jamie McNaught: same thing on command line: i get the source code instead of file csv

Comment: @Babu887 - then you're probably missing a parameter or something. Until you can get it to work with curl on the command line there's probably little point in trying to get it to work in php.

Comment: @JamieMcNaught: Ok you were right :-): there was a missing parameter in the POST string. Now i've got another problem: i receive an incomplete file. They probably take data from two different table, using a joint, and then put values in one csv. I receive only the first six columns of the final document.

Comment: Another thing: I've use CURLOPT_STDERR to get logs from the web page. I've notice that the file that i recive by curl is different from the one that is given in the browser. I'll explain: when i download the file from the browser i get PageName_XXX_1_12.csv and the name depends from pagename, from curl i get always Candidature_XXX_1_12.csv, where candidature is a pagename. I suppose they alway create this basic file first, and then, if necessary they modify it, adding columns.

Comment: In that case it sounds like you still don't know the API to the server and need to reverse engineer that. You should use the developer tools in your browser to log the network requests going to the server and try to recreate these exactly. It's possible that multiple requests are sent to 'build up' the document you are requesting. A number of internet banking websites work in this manner.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grabbing CSV over cURL in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160793/grabbing-csv-over-curl-in-php)